# jQuery/JavaScript facebook thumbnail update

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to get background-image url and replace with meta og:image property:

```js
function getBackgroundImageUrl($element) {
  if (!($element instanceof jQuery)) {
    $element = $($element);
  }

  var imageUrl = $element.css('background-image');
  return imageUrl.replace(/(url\(|\))/gi, '');
}

var image = getBackgroundImageUrl(".et_pb_slide.et_pb_bg_layout_dark.et_pb_media_alignment_center.et-pb-active-slide");
$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", image);
```

Function properly gets background-image url, but meta tag is still empty.
Any idea?

Comment: How are you determining the meta tag is still empty? Your code looks like it would work to me, although I'm not certain that Facebook will respect change made to `og:` tags via JS code

Comment: I'm checking it in inspect and Sharing Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: You can not update the OG meta data via client-side JavaScript - the Facebook scraper does not care about that. It only looks at the HTML the URL returns.